# foreign key relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two model class in rails.

```
class EmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :department_id
  belongs_to :department, :class_name => "Department", :foreign_key => :department_id
end
```

and

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

i have to create a foreign key relation between these two classes. but when i see the `employee_details` table, `department_id` is just a integer column without reference to department table. can any one please help to create foreign key relation. thnks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to. Rails do all the work for it.

What you can do is add an `index` in a migration. Like:

```
add_index :employee_details, :department_id
```

Comment: after adding add_index to migrate file, when i run the commmand rake db:migrate, it is showing error  PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "employee_details" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to Department model:

> has_many :employeedetails

Maybe, you don't need

> , :class_name => "Department", :foreign_key => :department_id

because Rails do it for you automatic